# Sharing mustache/nustache templates between server and client. ASP.NET MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, templates, razor, mustache

I`m using **mustache.js** on client and **Nustache** in ASP.NET MVC3 project.

I have `Person.mustache` template in a View folder on server, which I use like this:

```
@Html.Partial("Person")
```

from Razor main view (`Index.cshtml`).

But how can I transfer it to client? Browser has no access to Views folder to get raw content of a template. Somehow I must have a way to include to output HTML raw text of Person.mustache template on server. If I require it from Razor view, it compiles it, since it is normal server template engine.

Please anyone can give any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I`ve made something, that works, maybe somebody will come up with better solution. Here it is:

Extenstion for @Html helper:

```
public static class ViewExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString RenderRawContent(this HtmlHelper helper, string serverPath)
    {
        string filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(serverPath);

        //load from file
        StreamReader streamReader = File.OpenText(filePath);
        string markup = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        streamReader.Close();

        return new HtmlString(markup);

    }
}
```

And in Razor main view for Index page

```
@using MyProject.Helpers;

<script type="text/template" id="person_template">

    @Html.RenderRawContent("~/Templates/Person.mustache")

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll likely want to expose a new controller that can return your partial view content. E.g.:

```
public class TemplateController : Controller
{
  public PartialViewResult Get(string name)
  {
    return PartialView(name);
  }
}
```

With that, and a route:

```
routes.MapRoute("Templates", "templates/{name}",
  new { controller = "Template", action = "Get" });
```

I can then call from the client (in this example I am using jQuery):

```
var model = { name: "Matt" };
$.ajax({
  url: "/templates/person",
  success: function(r) {
    var html = Mustache.render(r, model);
    $("body").append(html);
  }
});
```

Comment: Couldn`t get this to work. What namespace "Partial" class is in? I found only "PartialView", but it compiles template with given model

Comment: Thanks for edit. But PartialView "Creates a PartialViewResult object that renders a partial view" - from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.web.mvc.controller.partialview.aspx , when I need raw content of template with all that {{}} symbols

Answer (score 0):

Name the file `Person.mustache.cshtml`, and in `Index.cshtml`:

```
<script type="text/template" id="person_template">
    @Html.Partial("Person.mustache")
<script type="text/template" id="person_template">
```

There's no need to write a helper to serve a file when the framework does that for you.

Comment: With that approach I wouldn`t be able to use Person.mustache as server template, if I rename it like this